# Is it possible to open links from push notifications inside my app without the need to store the link previously inside the app?

Tags: android, push-notification, deep-linking

I have a bunch of different marketing campaigns with links that change all the time. This campaigns are sent via push notifications to the users. When the link is clicked,  the sistem asks the user in which app he/she would like to open the link. If the user choose the app instead of a browser, the app opens and the link is missed.

I did some search and found that, in order to open a link inside the application, I need to store this link in the app. The problem with this approach is that the campaigns and links change all the time, so I would have to launch a new app version in production every time a campaign changes its link and it is insane.

Would anybody have a suggestion for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a better service for it like firebase dynamic links or Branch.io.
Using these services you can always open the app and get the data from the link(the user clicked) using the SDK provided by these services. Doesn't matter if the app is opened or web on clicking the link.

Comment: I haven't tried Branch.io, but Firebase Dynamic Link doesn't give me the option to open in both app and browser. I have to choose one of them.

Comment: Branch would have you covered there, I really liked their platform even though I have not used all the implementations possible. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could.
in our team we are using [braze sdk](https://www.braze.com/docs/user_guide/message_building_by_channel/push) for attaching deep link for pushes.
[image]

Here you should point out the deep link with your custom scheme (you already should have it implemented in your app)

if you don't want to use custom sdk for deep links (like firebase, appsflyer etc) - you could implement 'native' option by this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

another option to attach deep link to push (anyway you need to trigger it from some Back office or server) I don't know